# Create a dropdown of Sharepoint Groups with group name beginning with "NEC"

Tags: groups

I'd like to filter by group name using wildcard, something like this `NEC*`

Do I use SPServices or how can this be done?

Comment: You need to add some context, like where do you want this? What technologies are you comfortable with / allowed to use?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use CAMLQuery on SPService to query the SharePoint Groups.

So the best idea that I have so far is get all the Groups using GetGroupCollection method on SPServices (http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Users%20and%20Groups)
Then you can filter the result, that looks like that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774837.aspx.

The best way is using a JQUery plugin like this: http://outwestmedia.com/jquery-plugins/xmldom/

Then you will be able to type a query like

```
var xml = '<item><title>Hello world!</title></item>';
$.xmlDOM( xml )
    .find('item > title')
        .each(function() {
            // Alert's 'Hello world!'
            alert( $(this).text() );
        });
```

Comment: Can we Query SharePoint User Groups with CAML ? I didn't know about that..

Comment: I had misunderstood your question but the update should be ok